# Axios POST request not working with the Django-RestFramework

Tags: api, vuejs2, django-rest-framework, axios, postman

When I try To post with The Postman App it works perfectly Fine but When I post with The VUE-Axios it shows error 400 Bad Request So please help me out with this.
Also the GET request works perfectly fine

Only issue is with the POST request
Also with the default interface of API view it works fine
Please suggest change in Vue Code
PS i am a beginner in Vue and api interaction

This is The Vue Code

```
var app = new Vue(
    {
    el:"#app",
    delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
    data:
    {
        message: "Integrated With VUE",
    },
    mounted: function(){
        axios.get('api/movie')
        .then(response => console.log(response));
    },
    methods : {
        postData() {
            axios.post('api/movie/', {
                params:
                {   
                id : 10,
                title: "Random",
                rating: 5,
                type: "4",
                description: "This is another test data",
                torrent: "",
                date_added: "Auto_Add"}
            },
            {headers :   {"X-CSRFToken": csrftoken},

        }).then( (response)=> {console.log(response); });
        }
    }
});
```

In Django View I have This

```
class MovieAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        movies = Movie.objects.all()
        serializer = MovieSerializer(movies, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = MovieSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            print("Valid Serializer")
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In Django Serializer I have This

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Movie
            fields = ['id', 'title', 'rating', 'type', 'description', 'torrent', 'date_added']
```

Comment: It may be the validation errors. Could you provide the `Movie` model implementaion?